# Problemas con session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter

Tags: php, mvc, poo

Estoy haciendo un inicio de sesión usando el modelo MVC en PHP y tengo un problema de

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\backEndEmisoraSanJoseObrero\views\modules\navegacion.php:1) in C:\xampp\htdocs\backEndEmisoraSanJoseObrero\controllers\controller.php on line 43

y

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\backEndEmisoraSanJoseObrero\views\modules\navegacion.php:1) in C:\xampp\htdocs\backEndEmisoraSanJoseObrero\controllers\controller.php on line 42**

Al querer trabajar con las sesiones

El Formulario es este:

```html
<center>
 <div class="admin">
  <h1 class="ingresoTitle">Inicio de Sesion del Administrador</h1>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" name="usuarioIngreso">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="passwordIngreso">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form> 
 </div> 
</center>

<?php  
$ingreso = new MvcController(); //Creamos un nuevo objeto
$ingreso -> inicioSesionController(); //llamamos la funcion
?>
```

Y el código PHP que maneja el formulario éste:

```
public function inicioSesionController(){


    if (isset($_POST['usuarioIngreso'])) {

        if ($_POST['usuarioIngreso'] == 'admin') {
            header('location=ok');
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['user']= true;
        }

    }
}
}
```

Llevo días mirando mi código, cambiando y probando y no encuentro el problema.

Para entrar al formulario se usa un enlace GET que es `?action=admin`

El código completo en GitHub:https://github.com/darguello1998/emisorasanjoseobrerofm

Lo raro es que este inicio de sesión usa la misma técnica y no lanza error
https://github.com/darguello1998/iniciodesesiomvc

Comment: creo que lo que te falta es el session_start();

Comment: Tiene el session_start();

Comment: Lo primero que debe ir es el `session_start()`, y luego el `header(location...)`. Lo tienes al revés. Por cierto, ¿en tu `header`  lo que va es sencillamente `ok`? ¿Con qué fines haces eso?

Comment: Ya cambie y sigue el mismo error

Comment: No veo el archivo `navegacion.php` en ningún lado, ¿qué hay al principio de ese archivo? Ya lo vi y creo que no tienes control del orden en que se ejecutan las cosas. Lo primero de todo debe ser `session_start()` y antes de los header location no debe haber nada que salga por pantalla. Si tú usas o incluyes antes de todo eso el contenido de `navigation.php` vas a tener error. Considera que `session_start()`  debe ser el punto de entrada de tu programa y debe estar en el primer archivo que se ejecuta.

Comment: Gracias, en el caso de https://github.com/darguello1998/iniciodesesiomvc este codigo por que funcionaria? Porque use la misma tecnica de inicio de session

Comment: Funciona porque en ese caso no hay nada que aparezca antes de `session_start` y de `header location`. Pero aquí es evidente que, por la forma en que estás organizando las cosas, estás presentando contenido en pantalla antes y por eso no te funciona. Eso se nota en el mismo código PHP que tienes en la pregunta, si te fijas bien, primero presentas contenido HTML y luego llamas a `inicioSesionController()`. En un modelo `MVC` tú no puedes presentar nada sin pasar por el controlador... la parte inicial de tu código debería ser parte de la vista, por tanto, estás violando el paradigma MVC.

Comment: Al parecer si quito los meta tags del head el codigo no manda error :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respecto de tu código:

- Si vas a trabajar con sesiones, y tu tu `php.ini` no tiene `session.auto_start` habilitado, tú mismo inicializas la sesión y es de las primeras cosas que haces. No lo haces dentro de un método.
- si imprimes texto (en tu caso imprimes el HTML primero) no puedes modificar los headers a posteriori. Los header se enviaron implícitamente apenas escribiste un caracter. Misma cosas con las sesiones, no puedes meterle mano después que se enviaron los headers.
- `header('location=ok')` me intriga. ¿Es un código arbitrario que quieres luego inspeccionar desde el front? Porque si quisieras redirigir, entonces la sintaxis sería [header('Location: URL_DESTINO');](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php). Supongamos que está ahí para efectos de debug y no tiene efectos secundarios.

Resumiendo:

```
<?php  
session_start();
$ingreso = new MvcController(); //Creamos un nuevo objeto
$ingreso->inicioSesionController(); //llamamos la funcion
?>

<center>
    <div class="admin">
        <h1 class="ingresoTitle">Inicio de Sesion del Administrador</h1>
        <form method="post">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" name="usuarioIngreso">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="passwordIngreso">
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form> 
    </div>  
</center>
```

Y quitas el session_start del método `MvcController::inicioSesionController`

---

**Tip:**

MVC es un patrón de diseño (o patrón de arquitectura de software), no un modelo. Si dices "*Modelo MVC*" es como decir "*Modelo Modelo Vista Controlador*". Tienes que aprender esas cosas para que cuando llegue alguien del área comercial puedas marearlo con terminología que no entienda, pero siempre cuidándote de citar la terminología correcta. Es un tip para lidiar con jefes y clientes.

Para ser mas exacto, MVC NO es un patrón de diseño, sino un patrón Arquitectónico.